# Php classes inside php class

Tags: php

I am very new in php and my question title might seem pretty unclear. I am sorry for that. I try to explain here.

I have a checkout.php class that is main class.
In the class I have three different parts **shipping**, **payment** and **receipt**. While making checkout.php class I made those just using divs. Now I realize that does not work because after the buyer fills the form in **shipping** part and press continue button the data needed to pass to another part that is **payment**. I realize it is not possible to pass the data into the same php class. What do you suggest me to do in this case. I want **shipping**, **payment** and **receipt** to be different classes like *checkout.php/shipping*, *checkout.php/payment* and *checkout.php/receipt* respectively without changing the design. How can I achieve this?

```
<div class="checkout_nav">
   <ul>
      <li><a class="link_nav_1" href="#" rel="shipping">  <?php echo $lang['Shipping']; ?></a></li>
      <li><a class="link_nav_2" href="#" rel="payment">  <?php echo $lang['Payment']; ?></a></li>
      <li><a class="link_nav_3" href="#" rel="receipt">  <?php echo $lang['Receipt']; ?></a></li>
   </ul>
</div>

<div id="first_nav">

   <form action="payment.php" class="form" method="post" name="form" onsubmit="return validateForm();">

       <input name="firstname" type="text" id="first_name" placeholder="<?php echo $lang['First name']; ?>" class="required"/>
       <input name="lastname" type="text" id="last_name" placeholder="<?php echo $lang['Last name']; ?>" class="required"/>
       <input name="address1" type="text" id="address1" placeholder="<?php echo $lang['Address line 1']; ?>" class="required"/>
       <input name="address2" type="text" id="address2" placeholder="<?php echo $lang['Address line 2']; ?>"/>
       <input name="city"  type="text" id="city" placeholder="<?php echo $lang['City']; ?>" class="required"/>
       <input name="zipcode" type="text" id="zip" placeholder="<?php echo $lang['Zip code']; ?>" class="required"/>
       <input name="amount" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $mycart_total_price;  ?>"/>
       <select name="country" placeholder="Choose" style="width:280px">
           <option>Finland</option>
           <option>Sweden</option>
           <option>Norway</option>
       </select><br>
       <input name="delivery_submit" class="btn" id="btn" type="submit" value="<?php echo $lang['Continue']; ?>" />

   </form>
</div>

<div id="second_nav" style="display: none;">
   <h1>Payment</h1>
</div>
<div id="third_nav" style="display: none">
   <h1>Receipt</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: It would be great if you can add some code to your question so we can visualize your issue. Thanks!

Comment: To persist data across pages, you could use sessions (basic info: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp). Data from session an be used to populate your classes

Comment: @milz that´s how I have made my divs ito checkout.php class.

Comment: @zfus i know what you are trying to say to me. But that¨s not what i was searching for.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a language that runs once, and then dies. **You need to use sessions or a database to store the information for recall later.** This is standard PHP development stuff here, and it's not very complicated.

As far as getting your data between the classes, you can inject whatever data you need the second or third classes to have into the class when you call the constructor, or have them populate their own local version of it.

It sounds like you are having a design issue here though - what you probably need is an 'Order' class to hold the details, and then the 'Order' class can be passed into the 'Shipping' 'Receiving' and 'Payment' class so that they have access to it's details for processing. The order class can be passed up into your session to manage to avoid having to reload it from a database (or to re-instantiate the class every time you need it) and read back out of session on every page that needs to make use of it.

Comment: i did not understand much what you trying to say. I have checkout class where I have shipping, payment and order div.What I want is to process my payment system in my web store without messing up the design. If I click the checkout button I go to checkout page. Inside that page I have shipping div that contains form. When user fills form and click continue, he/she should go to payment page for payment process  using like this URL: ..../checkout.php/payment This page is like this: https://neuhaus.fi/checkout/address